# Ruby on Rails + Paperclip + Facebox: Image loads as text instead of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, facebox

here is what happens when I load an image with an absolute URL:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Help/Screen%20shot%202011-08-31%20at%2011.17.44%20AM%20copy.png

What is causing the image not to be rendered as an image?

Is it an issue with Facebox?

This is how I made the image link:

```
<a href="images/stairs.jpg" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

Just like on the website http://defunkt.io/facebox/

The download method:

```
  def download
    head(:not_found) and return if (media = Media.find_by_id(params[:id])).nil?

    path = media.document.path(params[:style])
    head(:bad_request) and return unless File.exist?(path) && params[:format].to_s == File.extname(path).gsub(/^\.+/, '')

    send_file_options = { :disposition => 'inline', :type => media.document.content_type }
    send_file_options = { :disposition => 'inline' } if File.extname(path) == ".swf" && media.document_content_type == "application/x-shockwave-flash"

    case SEND_FILE_METHOD
      when :apache then send_file_options[:x_sendfile] = true
      when :nginx then head(:x_accel_redirect => path.gsub(Rails.root, ''), :content_type => send_file_options[:type]) and return
    end

    send_file(path, send_file_options)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a MIME type error, where you're returning it as HTML or something interpreted as HTML. If you're using `send_file`, be sure to set your response MIME type. This is the `:type` option for `send_file`.

Comment: it is currently set to: :type => media.document.content_type

Comment: Just be sure it's set to something. A good way to check is with the command line tool `curl -I` which will show you the headers it received. A PNG image should be `image/png`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch facebox.js with the following patch.

https://github.com/ipavelek/facebox/commit/e4a0101596cd269f8337920564c8d33e193e8cbe

Facebox doesn't handle the URL query param that rails appends to images.